# I accidentally created a file called / and another call --reporter, how do I delete them?

Tags: bash, shell

I've accidentally created a file called / and one called --reporter=test and now I can't delete them, attempting to delete the --reporter file results in
   rm: illegal option -- -

I haven't attempted to delete the one called / I'm too scared, help!!

Comment: what commands are you using? Are you using quotes?
This will give some info about quoting http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html
Also for the / file it might be safe to be specific as in .//

Comment: how did you create the file `/` ?

Comment: What operating system or file system are you using? Since `/` is the path separator for most (all?) non-Windows file systems, it shouldn't even be possible to create such a file on those file systems.

Comment: Sorry should have put some more detail in there. I'm on OS X 

I've tried quoting with both double and single and also escaping with \ none of those have worked, deleting in finder also doesn't work.


As for creating the file called / I have no idea how it happened, I'm writing an app that creates HTML reports and it created it for some reason.

Comment: OS X exchanges `:` and `/` in file names for display (in deference to its historical usage of `:` as path component separator). If from a shell you made a file called `foo:bar`, `ls` would show it as `foo:bar`, but it would show up in the Finder as `foo/bar`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
rm ./--reporter=test
```

should get rid of the first one... I'm not sure about "/" ... can't seem to create one myself. How did you do that?

Comment: Also `rm -- --reporter=test`.

Comment: @SvendHansen Thanks this worked great. I also managed to delete the other file in finder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually going to say this in case it helps anyone:

After about 15 minutes of stackoverflow browsing to solve the mistake of creating a folder called `~`, I remembered there is such a thing as a mouse, and went to the folder to delete it.

Won't work on a server, of course.